# Making menu stay after cliking on it

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, menu

http://jsfiddle.net/2N9Y8/

Hello!
Here is my menu!
What I want now is that when I click on Program I want the dropdown menu to still be displayed, but not quite sure how to do it. 
IF anyone also have a clue on how i also can make the dropdown menu stay after i've clicked a link in the dropdown menu that would be nice(when i get directed to another page)

http://jsfiddle.net/2N9Y8/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Nösnäs</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mobilemenu.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").on('click',function () {
            $(".nav-button,.nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button>





<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Program</a>
<div class="second nav">
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Teknik</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Naturvetenskap</a></li>
<li><a href="#">El</a></li>
</ul></li>
</div>
  <li><a href="#">Nösnäs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Schema</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Matsal</a></li>
   </ul>




<style>.xg_module_body img {margin:0!important;}</style>
<span class="bilder">
<div align="center"><table cellpadding="0" width="150"  cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="facebookpic.png" title="Gilla våran Facebook sida" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#"target="_blank"><img src="googlepic.png" title="Gilla oss på googlde+" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="twitterpic.png" title="Följ oss på Twitter" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target=""><img src="rsspic.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" title="Följ våran RSS"></a></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</span>

<style>.xg_module_body img {margin:0!important;}</style>
<span class="bilderna">
<div align="center"><table cellpadding="0" width="150"  cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="facebookpic.png" title="Gilla våran Facebook sida" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#"target="_blank"><img src="googlepic.png" title="Gilla oss på googlde+" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="twitterpic.png" title="Följ oss på Twitter" width="35" height="35" border="0"></a></td>

<td><a href="#" target=""><img src="rsspic.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" title="Följ våran RSS"></a></td>
</tr>
</table></div>
</span>


</body>
</html>


* { margin:0;
padding:0;
}

html {height: 100%;}

body{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;

}



/* Första boxarna*/
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    position: relative;
    top: :0px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:0;
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
    background: url(sh.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
    display: list-item;
    font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
    font-size: 18px;

}




li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/* När jag drar musen över */
ul.nav li a  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    color: #174867;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    background: #ebebeb url(border.png) no-repeat;
    color: #67a5cd;
    padding: 9px 15px 7px 30px;
}
ul.nav li ul { 
display:none;
}
ul.nav li:active ul { 
display:block;
position:relative;
left:3px;
top:0px;
list-style: none;
z-index:999;
background: #888;
}

ul.nav li ul li
{ 
background:#888;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    javascript

    $(".program").on('click',function () {
                    $('li div ul').toggle('.close'); // new added
                    $('li div ul').show();

            });


    css

    .close{display:none;} // new added
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2N9Y8/2/

Comment: Thanks alot, couldnt quite get it to work on the live site for some reason, but hopefully ill figure it out! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In you css   
ul.nav li ul { 
    display:none;
    }
   so thats why on click it is not displayed

I gave a class in li for the program li.
<li class="program"><a href="#">Program</a>



     Below is the javascript.



         $(".program").on('click',function () {
                            $('li div ul').show();

                    });
```

Js Fiddle demo  http://jsfiddle.net/2N9Y8/1/

Comment: Thanks alot! The problem with that tho is that when you've clicked it once, and then click it again to hide, it doesnt hide :/ Any clue hwo to fix it?

Comment: Please find below another demo which have hide functionality